# How to implement sticky section header in collection view in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

Here I am having sort and filter buttons which I need to make it as a header in collection view that to I need it like as sticky header view can any one help me how to implement this for this type of layout and below is my image for the grid layout and I tried by using this [link](https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-sticky-section-headers-to-a-collection-view) but unable to implement the layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrbC.jpg)

Comment: you want the header to be pinned to its position irrespective of scrolling or you want the header to scroll up with the section?

Comment: I want it to stay on top of section instead of scrolling @iOS_MIB

Comment: Add a UIView for sticky header & UICollectionView for grid layout separately.

Comment: but actually what the problem here is I am making navigation bar moving up and down animation along with scroll but when I place a view it is affecting so I am trying to make it as header @Rocky

Comment: [TLYShyNavBar](https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar) is a implementation of your requirement.

Comment: try this:
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout // casting is required because UICollectionViewLayout doesn't offer header pin. Its feature of UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true

Comment: this already tried but header has stopped but content on collection view was moving on top of them @iOS_MIB